# Deleting a dll using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Am having a batch file used to update certain files.
However when i try to delete a file from a specified folder i am getting error "Invalid syntax, directory".

The command is below
del /Q %INSTDIR%\xyz.dll

The %INSTDIR% is taken from registry and is correctly processing any copy commands. But am getting error for del command. Please help

Comment: Can you please add echo %INSTDIR% in your batch file and post the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
del /Q "%INSTDIR%\xyz.dll"
```

Most likely %INSTDIR% has spaces in it sometimes and thus the failure.  You must place double quotes around long file/folder names.